# Is there a way to remove a single line from the output of Rollup?

Tags: rollup

I am looking for a way to remove the first line of the rollup output file. I know I can do it with a script and say sed, but I am looking for something a little cleaner.

I tried plugins like [replace](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/replace) & [strip](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/strip) but these do not seem to let me "replace" a line of code.

Does anyone how to do this? Is there a plugin?

**Update**

Here is my current sed solution...

```
"build": "rollup -c && npm run fix:rollup",
"fix:rollup": "sed '1d' ./dist/index.js > ./tmp.js; mv ./tmp.js ./dist/index.js"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use writeBundle hook, sketch:

```
import fs from 'fs';//Node.js builtin
...
plugins:[
  {//inline plugin
    writeBundle(bundle){
      for (const [fileName, chunkOrAsset] of Object.entries(bundle)) {
        //test for file you want to modify
        const data = fs.readFileSync(fileName, {encoding:'utf8'});
        data.replace(/^[^\n]*\n/,'');
        fs.writeFileSync(...)
      }
  }
]
```

Comment: So let me understand what this is doing, is this rewriting the dull bundle at the end? Would I still have to know which fileName I am looking for?

Comment: the https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#writebundle hook is called by rollup after it has written the output. It gives you a {filename: ChunkInfo} map. Depending on your rollup configuration that can be as sinple as a single file or arbitrarily complex, therefore the for...of... loop. In the loop you can do a test if the current filename is what you want and then read, modify, safe the file