# Rollup - how to prevent CSS import from d.ts file?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, rollup, postcss

I have a React & Typescript / tailwind / postcss / Rollup setup to build a component library, at [this repo](https://github.com/rossbulat/polkadot-dashboard-ui).

Everything is working as intended apart from one issue; a corresponding import for `../styles/index.css` is being included in the outputted `dist/index.d.ts` file. I wish to have declarations for my components, but not this CSS import.

The problem is that this `index.css` file **is outside the dist directory**, and is not included in the final library. Instead, the **minified and purged** tailwind css file is being generated and used instead.

##### Current solution

I am currently relying on a post-build command to remove the import from the file using `sed`:

```
scripts: {
    ...
    "build": "rollup -c && cp dist.package.json dist/package.json",
    "fix": "sed '1d' ./dist/index.d.ts > ./tmp.d.ts; mv ./tmp.d.ts ./dist/index.d.ts",
}
```

I do not feel this is an optimal approach. If I can prevent the import in the build process instead, this would be preferred.

##### Similar issues

I found [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59034014/is-there-a-way-to-remove-a-single-line-from-the-output-of-rollup/59072880#59072880?newreg=3c15393768dd4037a6cbde973c97dc4a) but the pseudo code provided does not work / is not complete. Furthermore, this feels like a workaround rather than an actual fix.

##### rollup.config.js

For what it is worth, my current rollup config is as follows:

```
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import del from "rollup-plugin-delete";
import simplevars from "postcss-simple-vars";
import nested from "postcss-nested";
import cssnext from "postcss-cssnext";
import cssnano from "cssnano";

/**
 * @type {import('rollup').RollupOptions}
 */
export default {
  input: "lib/index.tsx",
  output: [
    {
      file: "dist/index.tsx",
      format: "es",
      sourcemap: false,
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    del({ targets: "dist/*" }),
    peerDepsExternal(),
    postcss({
      config: {
        path: "./postcss.config.js",
      },
      plugins: [
        simplevars(),
        nested(),
        cssnext({ warnForDuplicates: false }),
        cssnano(),
      ],
      extensions: [".css"],
      minimize: true,
      modules: false,
      extract: "index.css",
    }),
    resolve(),
    typescript({
      useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true,
    }),
  ],
};
```